# How to save result text after web scraping

Tags: python, save

I am studying Python to make a web scraper. This below code is good working by helping. Then I wonder how to save result? Could you help this issue?

```
import nltk
import urllib
import readability
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from readability.readability import Document
import mechanize

url = "http://www.nytimes.com/2015/06/02/science/medicines-hidden-roots-in-an-ancient-manuscript.html?ref=science&_r=0"

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]

html = br.open(url).read()

readable_article = Document(html).summary()
readable_title = Document(html).short_title()

soup = BeautifulSoup(readable_article)

final_article = soup.text

links = soup.findAll('img', src=True)

print final_article

output = zip(readable_article,readable_title)
writer = csv.writer(open('newyorktimes.csv', 'wb'))
writer.writerows(final_article)

 exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bunch of typos:

You're doing:

```
from readabiliry.radability import Document
#             ^   ^
```

and you should import

```
from readability.readability import Document
```